# Problems unloading xml (movieclip) when changing to another frame

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, movieclip

I need some help. I loaded xml on a movieclip and i also have a button to go to another frame but the xml keeps loadding!! what can i do to remove the xml each time i click on that button?

I'm using flash cs4 AS3.Please help

Answer (score 0):

you could just delete your loader content.

```
delete myLoader.content;
```

Or once you load you xml content, you could just remove and delete your loader from stage:

```
removeChild(myLoader);
delete myLoader;
```